# SSH keeps complaining about identification change (Permanent Solution?)

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I need to ssh into the various  OSes in the same machine.One of the problems i face with this is that whenever I do this ssh complains

```
 WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!
```

I have a temporary work around this which is to remove the keys in

```
/Users/XYZ/.ssh/known_hosts
```

but I have to do this day in and day out and so it is irritating to delete it everytime .Is there a permanent solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The host-key checking is really important to detect "man-in-the-middle" attacks,
so it is not recommended to disable it, but you can skip that check with the following option,

```
ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" user@hostname
```

Comment: the above option doesnt seem to work.I still get the same warning.